# Java: Get writer into String?

Tags: java, writer

I am making kinda text generator, I wrote this function which builds an output text file. However - I have two options in app - Save to File and Copy to Clipboard.

Save to file works perfect, but genQC(false) means it wants to generate text and copy it to clipboard. How can I basically get this writer into a String?
I am new to writers/file handling in java so I am unsure of such case.

```
 public void genQC(boolean save){
        if(save == true){
            try{
        File file = new File(fcs.getSetting("workingDir", "Not Set")+"\\"+smdFileName+".qc");
        JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser(fcs.getSetting("workingDir", "C:"));
        f.setSelectedFile(file);
        f.showSaveDialog(null);
        String selectedPath = String.valueOf(f.getSelectedFile());
        System.out.println(selectedPath);


        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(selectedPath, "UTF-8");
        writer.println("$modelname \""+modelFinalPath+modelFinalName+".mdl\"");
        writer.println("$scale "+ (scale / 10));
        if(staticprop == true){
            writer.println("$staticprop");
        }
        writer.println("$bodygroup \"Body\"");
        writer.println("{");
        writer.println("\tstudio \""+refPath+"\"");
        writer.println("}");
        writer.println("$cdmaterials \""+materialsFinalPath+"\"");
        writer.println("$surfaceprop \""+surfaceProp+"\"");
        writer.println("$sequence idle \""+refPath+"\" loop fps 15");
        if(nocollision == false){
            if(defcollision == true){
                writer.println("$collisionmodel \""+refPath+"\"");
            }
            else if(defcollision == false){
                writer.println("$collisionmodel \""+colPath+"\"");
            }
            writer.println("{");
            if(automass == false){
            writer.println("\t$mass "+mass);
            }
            else{
            writer.println("\t$automass");    
            }
            writer.println("\t$concave");
            writer.println("}");

        }
        else{
            //Nothing
        }
        writer.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(save == false){
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection ("ehh");
            Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
            clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
        }




    }
```

I assume I need to else if block or something?

Comment: just saying use `(save){}` instead of `(save == true){} `both are same

Comment: Move your code into a method that takes a `Writer`. Now just pass in a `FileWriter` or a `StringWriter` as required.

Comment: First, use a `StringBuilder` to create the whole output. Then you can still decide whether you want to write it to a file or copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: Some style notes: First, as Fast Snail said, don't compare booleans. use `if (save)` rather than `if (save==true)`, and `if ( ! nocollision )` rather than `if ( collision == false )`. Second, don't do something like `else{}`. Just drop the `else` part. Third, indent properly: everything inside curly braces should be indented one level to the right. You can read the [Code formatting guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) by Oracle, or refer to those of Google.